# Get value of field that is in class which is also field in another class

Tags: c#, reflection, fieldinfo

So, lets start from code so I can better explain myself. I have MyClass class, which contains an int field, also Foo class contains MyClass as field. I want to get value of int field from MyClass using reflection.

```
public class Foo
{
 public MyClass myClass;
}

public class MyClass
{
 public int Integer = 1;
}
```

When i use

```
Foo f = new Foo();
foreach(FieldInfo fi in f.GetType().GetFields())
{
 //lets say now it enumerating myClass field
 foreach(FieldInfo fi2 in fi.FieldType.GetFields())
 {
  return fi2.GetValue(f); //Here I need to use f.myClass, but I can't
  //because it's generic method and I don't know what type I'm currently
  //enumerating, so just typing f.myClass won't make it
 }
}
```

The question is how do I get value of f.myClass.Integer?
Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: It would be interesting to see your use-case here.

Comment: @ByteBlast I'm writing custom serialization solution for my project in Unity3D engine. So the serializer class will look someting like this Serializer<T> { void Serialize(string fileName, object serializedObject); T Deserialize(string fileName, out object deserializedObject); }

Answer (score -1):

Any particular reason why you have to use reflection in this instance? If you're just trying to get at the value of that instance method, you can do the following:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
var myInt = f.myClass.Integer;
```

Comment: Oh, I'm writing custom serialization solution for my project in Unity3D engine. So the serializer class will look someting like this
class Serializer<T>
{
void Serialize(string fileName, object serializedObject);
T Deserialize(string fileName, out object deserializedObject);
}  
(Strange someone down-voted this answer)